# stange output with split a string from file by a space

Tags: c

counter.txt

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

```
void  split_str(char line_str[10]) {

    int i, j;
    i=0;

    char  sub_str[10][20];   
    char  *token;

    token = strtok(line_str," ");     

    while (token != NULL) {
        strcpy(sub_str[i], token);   
        i=i+1;
        token=strtok(NULL," ");   
    }   

    for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
        printf("The char is %s\n",sub_str[j]);


} //split_str

void main() {

    file_ptr=fopen("counter.txt", "r");

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file_ptr ) != NULL ) { 
        split_str(line);
    }      

    fclose ( file_ptr );
}
```

Result:
The char is 1
The char is 2
The char is 3

The char is 。" //a space with double quota
The char is 4
The char is 5
The char is 6

The char is 。"
The char is 7
The char is 8
The char is 9
The char is 。"

。is space, this web site trimmed

there are some char " "" a space with double quota that i unexpected, what is that?
thanks

Comment: Note that I rolled back your edit deleting the question's content. This is not how SO works :) If your problem was resolved, say thanks, accept the answer and move on. Maybe someone with a similar problem can then benefit from your question and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is garbage data in `sub_str` because this code is incorrect:

```
while (token != NULL) {
    strcpy(sub_str[i], token);   
    i=i+1;
    token=strtok(NULL," ");   
}   

for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
    printf("%s\n",sub_str[j]);
```

The `for` loop should run until `j < i` here. This is because at `sub_str[i]` you just have some dummy value, since after `i=i+1` you exit the `while` loop on the NULL token.

Try to simulate it "in your head" or run in a debugger to see the problem in action.

Comment: @friends: you're welcome. I rolled back the original question though - why change it? To "close the issue" just accept the answer, and you're good to go